# Detecting Wall Collision

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

In my game, I have multiple zombies and a player. I have imported city (created using osm in blender) in to my scene.

Now i want, My Zombies should detect the wall collision (If happened with them) and should move towards to the player.

I have used `transform.LookAt(target);` so that the Zombies should look for him unless die/destroyed.

I have tagged the wall as 'wall' and detecting the wall collision/trigger with zombies, so that i should not cross in between the walls, and OnTriggerEnter , gameObject is rotating at 90.

Now the problem is when the Zombie touch the wall, collision/trigger happens and Zombie rotate @ 90 and starts moving, but it keeps on moving.. I want once the wall end, he should again start moving towards Player..

Any Logical idea or a script please.

Comment: Please include some code with your question so we have something to work with.  Your problem could be caused by the collision being fired repeatedly, logic getting called each frame, etc. Please update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical idea:
make a collider as trigger such that the zombie would enter it and then turn 90 degree. Then it will turn towards player on exit.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   //zombie turn (avoid wall)
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
  //zombie chases the player by rotating -90degeree or whatever the angle it changed on entering the trigger
}
```